# Smart Git unable to access the git repository

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, smartgit

I'm using smart git 7 for version management on ubuntu 14.04, but when I try to pull or push from my machine the I get the following error

Pull (Merge, no commit): unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/salyani/fulmala/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org

I'm new to ubuntu and smartgit. How to solve it? Or is there any other better git client than smartgit for linux?

Comment: What happens when invoking `git fetch` from command line (in your repository root?

Comment: It says fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/salyani/fulmala/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "INDEX" file in the .git folder.